# What combination of toolsets is cost effective for hosting an intranet website?

Tags: database, web-development, ide, web-server

Conditions:

- I need to be able to support a database that is small and multi-user access
- I need server-side and client-side programming/scripting
- I need it to be license free - or low cost, yet reasonably secure
- I need it to support multiple browser types

Example:
  Presently, I'm using a combination of:

- MySQL
- VisualStudio2013 c#/asp.net
- JavaScript (not jscript)
- IIS

So far only the VS13 has a licence utilized that had been purchased prior to the requirements.

I have had difficulty getting all of the features to work, partially because I am as yet not familiar with these systems.

In the past I have used Oracle SQL with ColdFusion, but we also had an in house tool suite we used for deployment.

Recommendations for Cost-effective solutions are appreciated.  Regardless of the method I will have to study up on it to get the familiarity required.

**Additional constraints:**

- I do not have the option of selecting operating systems.
- Presently available are: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Is both Free adn free good enough? BSD or Linux, MySQL or MariaDB, Apache webserver, PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for home projects where I have more flexibility.

With the additional OS constraints, do you have any changes to your recommendation?

Comment: Note that you can still run Apache/PHP/MySql or MariaDB on Windows.

Comment: @wolfsshield as Z Z states, you can run the same stack on Windows.  I personally wouldn't trust Windows as a server on the Internet, but for an Intranet you should be OK.

Comment: I totally agree with @ivanivan - if internet use Unix/Linux. For intranet, you may have to use Windows due to internal constraints. But go with Apache/PHP/MySql/MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Apache with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html). Recently I have installed a system running Jira, Confluence and Mattermost. The database was PostgreSQL. All applications are hidden behind Apache and mod_proxy. You can extend this setup easily with Node.js scripts on the server side implementing some REST APIs, which can be accessed from the client side by JavaScript programs. Confluence can be extended to include database queries in wiki tables.